# MS Access show data of only 30 days

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm struggling to create a query to get data from two tables where it needs to only show data of a sales rep for the first 30 days from the sales rep start date. Here are my tables.

Sales Rep Table

```
|ID | Name | Start Date|
```

Second Table would be all the sales of all the reps

```
|Order Date | Order Number | Sales Amount | REP ID |
```

I know you can Join and group by ID and get the total amount, but I only need the amount within the first 30 days of a reps start date.

Any help would be appreciated. I hope this makes sense?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join on Rep ID and apply a filter:

```
where [Order Date] Between [Start Date] and DateAdd("m", 1, [Start Date])
```